# How to bypass the effect of grep/egrep?

Tags: bash, grep

Let me make it clear.

I wrote a bash script which takes several arguments; it will first pass the arguments to command `ps`, for instance:

`$ ./myscript.sh -wef | egrep ".*somethingtomatch.*"`

the script will pass `-wef | egrep ".*somethingtomatch.*"` to `ps` to generate the result of `ps -wef | egrep ".*somethingtomatch.*"`,

and then the rest of my script will do something else and **it will have other outputs to the screen.**

However, since my original input to bash was `$ ./myscript.sh -wef | egrep ".*somethingtomatch.*"`, this makes my other outputs from the script invisible because of the effect of `egrep`.

What can I do to make those other outputs visible and also keep the original input format - I don't want to add extra quotes or other symbols to `$ ./myscript.sh -wef | egrep ".*somethingtomatch.*"`

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> the script will pass `-wef | egrep ".*somethingtomatch.*"` to `ps` to generate the result of `ps -wef | egrep ".*somethingtomatch.*"`

No, it will pass `-wef` to `ps` and then pipe the ouput of your program to `egrep ".*somethingtomatch.*"`.

You don't want to change your syntax, so there's no solution to your problem. Relax your constraints.

The easiest way would be to pass it as a second argument: `./myscript.sh -wef somethingtomatch`.

Answer (score 0):

You *cannot* have a naked pipe (`|`) as an argument. Period. You *will* need to escape it like `\|`. So, if you do not want to add any symbols to your call, your only solution is to write another shell, or build bash with another character to pipe....

Comment: Note that escaping the pipe sign won't help.

Comment: Erm, @KarolyHorvath: how do you mean? Because it will send the character `'|'` as an argument to `myscript.sh` here....

Comment: well, yes, you can write a script that can detect it and then filter the results but that would be a really ugly solution.

Comment: @Karoly: I still do not understand what/why you say the `\|` would not work. Take for instance http://pastebin.com/jdgMaeD7 . Where is the ugly hackishness of which you speak? Or are you referring to the fact that `ps $@;` won't work in the file, and the OP would have to use some other means, for example `eval "ps $@";`  to make that pipe work as a pipe again?

Comment: because he want's to grep... yes, I ment `eval`, but that can also cause unwanted sideeffects..

Comment: OK, then we understand each other: not the passing of `|` with `\|` to a script is the problem (which I thought you meant), but the reinterpreting it as an actual pipe again in a safe reliable manner in that script is the problem.